# Get visiting company name in rendering from Sitecore OMS

Tags: sitecore

We are using Sitecore OMS and I want to get the name of the visiting company (allthough I know that it is not allways accuarate) to show in a rendering.
Anyone know if it is possible to question the Analytics API for this kind of information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it by some help from [this blog post](http://sitecoresnippets.blogspot.com/2010/10/live-visitor-tracking-with-sitecore-oms.html)!

```
var sessionId = AnalyticsTracker.Current.CurrentSession.SessionId;
var IPOwner = AnalyticsManager.GetIpOwnerBySessionId(sessionId);
```

Answer (score 1):

An API for querying Analytics data doesn't (yet?) exist. Your best bet may be to use LINQ to SQL to get what you are looking for. Check out [this post](http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/en/Developers/Articles/2009/09/mostviewedList.aspx) for something similar.